# Getting a submenu in a navigation bar to show up

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, navigation

I am working on making my submenu in a navigation bar to show up. I had no trouble getting the first menu items to show up, but can't get the second sub-menu items to list. Here is what I have so far and I simply need to know what to do to get the second list items to show up in my navigation.

HTML:

```
    <body>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header">

    <p>Project 8</p>
        <div class="content">
     <div class="main">
 <ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="web.htm">Web</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="web115.htm">WEB-115</a></li>
        <li><a href="web210.htm">WEB-210</a></li>
        <li><a href="web215.htm">WEB-215</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="web-215-js.htm">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a href="web-215-jq.htm">jQuery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="web182.htm">WEB-182</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="dba.htm">Database</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="dba110.htm">DBA-110</a></li>
        <li><a href="dba120.htm">DBA-120</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul><br /></div>
<div id="footer">
<br />
<p class="clearleft">In Project 8, you will build a jQuery drop-down navigation bar with support    for 'you are here' link markers.</p></div>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

ul li {
float:left;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
background: #777;
text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color:#fff;
}

ul li li {
background: #777;
color: #fff;
display: none;
}

 ul li ul li ul li {
background: #777;
color: #fff;
position:absolute;
display: inline;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 100;
visibility: hidden;

}
/* 
LEVEL ONE
*/
 ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: bold; float: left; zoom: 1; background: #ccc; }
ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #000; }
ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #ffa500; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #333;
                                  color:    #222; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover                { background: #F3D673; color: black; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a              { color: black; }


/* 
LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                      { width: 220px; visibility:     hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; }
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #f6f6f6; color: #000; 
                                  border-     bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float: none; }

                                /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { border-right: none; width:     100%; display: inline-block; } 

/* 
LEVEL THREE
*/
ul.dropdown ul ul                   { left: 100%; top: 0; }
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul           { visibility: visible; }
#current {
border: 1px dashed #000;
width: 132px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
color:#FFF;
background: #000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* $("#navigation").navPlugin({
   'itemWidth': 150,
   'itemHeight': 30,
   'navEffect': "slide",
   'speed': 250
 });*/
 $('li').hover(function(){
 $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(400);
 });

 $(function(){

    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){

    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

    }, function(){

    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

        $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ").css ('visibility', 'visible');

 });


     youAreHere();
    }); // end ready

       function youAreHere() {
        var pathname = $(location).attr('pathname');
          var curPage = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
       //alert(curPage);
        $('a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href') == curPage) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'current');
        } else if(curPage == '') {
        $('a:first').attr('id', 'current');
        }
        else if(curPage == 'web215') {
        $(this).find('ul>li>ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(400);
       }//end else if
    });//end anonymous function

    }
```

I am currently taking a class and am totally new to jQuery.

Comment: okay can you please fiddle your big code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about?

Comment: go into jsfiddle.net and post your html, css and javascript code. run then save then press share and give us the link so we can help you. EDIT: something like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/qUem6/

Comment: You have the right code, only I have a js library attached to it. It shows up with the links for the one you are on in black and the only thing that isn't working is the two links beneath the Web-215 link - the JavaScript and Jquery links are the only two that aren't showing up correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qUem6/1/ - the code is not acting like it does normally though. The drop down menu is working, it is only the submenu items that don't show up. With the fiddle, I imagine because it isn't linked to jquery libraries, it doesn't show up the way it is in my editors. The only part that isn't working is the two links beneath the Web-215 link - If I could get those two to slide out it would be perfect. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Here is what it is doing - It took me a while to figure out how to use fiddle :) - http://jsfiddle.net/sMACh/